# How get customers collection for product who have this product in wishlist

Tags: php, magento

I have product. How I can get customers collection who have this product in wishlist.

Answer (score 1):

my guess is your looking to create some sort of cart or cart rendering? if so search for how to create a cart in php. There are alot of very useful videos on youtube and such. Generally you will want to incorporate sessions so customers can store info from page to page. Hope this helps.

Comment: No, I detect change in product (for example status 'out of stock' ) and send emails customers who subscribe this action.